# Creating a clickable div with 'link_to' syntax

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a clickable div but instead of using the full address for the link, I'd like to use ruby's 'link_to' syntax. How would I point to "facebook_path" instead of the full address?

```
<div id="item_1", onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"> Home </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using the following syntax:

```
<%= link_to "http://www.facebook.com", id:"item_1" do %>
  #your code here
<% end %>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Hey this is almost it! The position and font work. But the problem that arose is that the link now changes color when clicked and is underlined. Do you know how to remove that? Thanks

Comment: That is the default color of the link/href and it can be easily changed through css

Comment: And about that underline. Its also by default and it can also be removed using **text-decoration: none;** css property. But make sure you apply this property on anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are just using erb, but you can pass a block to the `link_to` helper. So your example would be:

```
<%= link_to 'http://www.facebook.com' do %>
  <div id="item_1" style="cursor:pointer;">
    Home
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the problem is that when I do this, the formatting and location I set for 'item_1' isn't used anymore. it reverts to a normal link. do you know how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Putting block elements inside inline elements isn't really the best thing to do, even though it is possible. I don't know exactly what you are doing but try changing your `div` element to a `span`.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your comments, let me explain the difference between `css` and `rails` (which is what your issue is):

You can create an `a` block by using the following code:

```
<%= link_to your_path_helper, class: "class", id: "id" do %>
   Stuff here
<% end %>
```

This will render the following HTML:

```
<a href="http://your_path.com/helper" class="class", id="id">Stuff here</a>
```

The question you have now is "how do I make this style the same as another element (div or similar)". The way to do this is to use `css`:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets.css
a.id {
   color: #000; /* makes the link color black */
   text-decoration: none; /* Removed underline */
}
```

CSS works by styling the different elements of your page. The `class` and `id` selectors allows you to identify the specific items, whilst the `css properties` help you pick the right styling

Your issue is you're trying to style your `a` element in the same way as your `div`. You need to select the `a` element & style that in your CSS